# Выход из цикла по истечении заданного времени

Tags: perl

Есть пополняемый файл, каждый день создается новый файл, в котором появляются записи. В файл за прошедший день, запись прекращается. Требуется его считать и распарсить, и записать в базу.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use File::Tail;
use DBI;
use Getopt::Long;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

$dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:phone', 'пользователь', 'пароль') or die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
$date_string = strftime "%d_%m_%Y", localtime;
    $filename = "/srv/cdr/cdr_log_26_04_2015.log";
unless (-e $filename){
    my $lfh;
    open($lfh, '>', $filename) or
    die "Unable to open file $filename : $!";
    close($lfh) or die "Unable to close file : $filename $!";
}

$file=File::Tail->new(name=>$filename);
my $time = time;
while ((defined($line=$file->read))||($time<=time+25*60*60)) {
        my @arr = split(" ", $line);
    #$arr[0] - Port Address A
    #$arr[1] - anumber
    #$arr[2] - bnumber
    #$arr[3] - Port Address B
    #$arr[4] - anumber fixed
    #$arr[5] - bnumber fixed
    #$arr[6] - date
    #$arr[7] - time
    #$arr[9] - duration
    #$arr[10] - code
    if (($arr[4] eq "-") && ($arr[5] eq "-")){
        $arr[4] = $arr[1];
        $arr[5] = $arr[2];
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO `phone` (`port_address_A`, `anumber`, `port_address_B`, `bnumber`, `duration`, `date`, `time`, `code`) VALUES('$arr[0]', '$arr[4]', '$arr[3]', '$arr[5]', '$arr[9]', STR_TO_DATE('$arr[6]', '%d-%m-%y'), STR_TO_DATE('$arr[7]', '%T'), '$arr[10]');\n";
    $dbh->do($query);
    undef @arr;
}
$dbh -> disconnect;
```

Не могу понять, почему скрипт весит в процессах больше суток. Ведь по условию он должен выйти из цикла через 25 часов. 
Вообще, в идеале, как-то его завершить, если в файле не появляются строчки на протяжении 6 часов, например.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15661388/815386

Comment: File::Tai а это не то?

Comment: нет, там же всё написано, используйте inotify, есть ещё вариант с select и переодичкой проверкой длины файла (если меньше, то truncated) простой варинат - убивайте свой скрипт в logrotate или посылайте ему signal 1 и обрабатывайте.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на условие `$time <= time + 25*60*60` еще раз. Попробуйте подставить сюда реальные значения. Вот, к примеру, $time - это 1 апреля. Допустим, сейчас уже третье апреля. Что получится в условии?

Comment: спасибо, нужно же $time <= time - 25*60*60

Comment: @IlyaKozlov Ну так точно не будет сутками висеть, да.

Comment: висит блин всеравно

Answer (score 0):

Вот же в документации `File::Tail` написано английским по белому:

```
read returns one line from the input file. If there are no lines ready, it blocks until there are.
```

Вызов `$file->read` блокируется и ждёт новые строки, которых уже никогда не будет. Ставьте будильник:

```
my $abort = !1;
my $time = time;

local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { $abort = 1; };
alarm 10;

while ( !$abort && defined($line = $file->read) ) {
    alarm 0; # чтобы не вылететь, когда уже прочитали
    last if $abort;

    # парсим строку, вставляем в БД…
    ...

    alarm 10;
}
```

Таким образом дольше 10 секунд скрипт блокироваться не будет.

Comment: Для будильников по коду очень удобственно юзать Time::Out.

Comment: Я бы к этому модулю осторожно относился, он $@ затирает. Если это держать в голове, то в целом неплохо смотрится.